# How to select avg from count in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new in sql and I want to know how can I select avg from count this is how my code looks like

```
Select zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa, count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) as licz
from zwierzeta
join klatki
on zwierzeta.zwierze_id = klatki.klatka_id
having count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) >= 1
GROUP BY zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa
```

Now I want to select avg from count(zwierzeta.klatka_id).

I have tried this method

```
Select zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa, count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) as licz, avg(licz) as avg_number
from zwierzeta
join klatki
on zwierzeta.zwierze_id = klatki.klatka_id
having count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) >= 1
GROUP BY zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa
`
```

but it doesnt recognize "licz"

Comment: 1.Exchange the order of the clauses `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`                                         
2.Please add and use aliases for the tables

Answer (score 0):

You have do it in another query

```
  SELECT zwierzeta_nazwa,zwierzeta_klatka_id,klatki_nazwa, 
  licz, avg(licz) as avg_number
  FROM (
  Select zwierzeta.nazwa as zwierzeta_nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id as zwierzeta_klatka_id,klatki.nazwa as klatki_nazwa, 
  count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) as licz
  from zwierzeta, klatki
  where zwierzeta.zwierze_id = klatki.klatka_id
  having count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) >= 1
 GROUP BY zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa)
 GROUP BY zwierzeta_nazwa,zwierzeta_klatka_id,klatki_nazwa, 
  licz
```

Comment: The problem is that for some reason when I am trying to do 
FROM (
  Select zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa, 
  count(zwierzeta.klatka_id) as licz
  from zwierzeta
  GROUP BY zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa)
 GROUP BY zwierzeta.nazwa,zwierzeta.klatka_id,klatki.nazwa, licz 
it gives me error ORA-00904: "KLATKI"."NAZWA": invalid identifier

Comment: I made a comment to how my code look like

Comment: i have modifed my code ,try now and let me know

Comment: Still have ORA-00904: "KLATKI"."NAZWA": invalid identifier. I am using Oracle Live SQL. Can it be a problem? I think that FOR () isn't working properly. I have tried this simpler code
  SELECT zwierzeta.nazwa, licz
  FROM
  (
    select count(zwierzeta.zwierze_id) as licz
    from zwierzeta
  )
and it doesn't work too

Comment: can you check if KLATKI table contains the column NAZWA

Comment: This is failing because you are trying to use table aliases in the outer query that are only defined in the inner query (and because you have column aliases that are identical).

Comment: @MT0 modified the answer to solve the issue pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVG` analytic function around the `COUNT` function. If you want an average over the entire result set then:

```sql
SELECT z.nazwa,
       z.klatka_id,
       k.nazwa,
       COUNT(z.klatka_id) as licz,
       AVG(COUNT(z.klatka_id)) OVER () as avg_number
FROM   zwierzeta z
       JOIN klatki k
       ON (z.zwierze_id = k.klatka_id)
GROUP BY
       z.nazwa,
       z.klatka_id,
       k.nazwa
HAVING COUNT(z.klatka_id) >= 1
```

If you want to average over sub-partitions of the result set then add a `PARTITION BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT z.nazwa,
       z.klatka_id,
       k.nazwa,
       COUNT(z.klatka_id) as licz,
       AVG(COUNT(z.klatka_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY z.nazwa, z.klatka_id) as avg_number
FROM   zwierzeta z
       JOIN klatki k
       ON (z.zwierze_id = k.klatka_id)
GROUP BY
       z.nazwa,
       z.klatka_id,
       k.nazwa
HAVING COUNT(z.klatka_id) >= 1
```